# Adding MVC Markup to a Class Outside of the Scope of the MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's the situation:

I have two projects. One is a C# class library, one is an MVC 5 project.

I have a class in the class library that has an "ID" field. I need this ID field to have the [key] and [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] MVC markup, but because it is not a part of the MVC5 project, I can't simply add the markup to the field.

How can I tell MVC that this field in this class outside of my project is the Key?? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont think the properties are MVC specific. You can use them I guess. They are in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace

Answer (score 0):

That's not MVC, that's Entity Framework.  [Specifically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute) this namespace:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```

in this assembly:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll)
```

You can simply add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to your Class Library project.  (Note that this means anything which uses that project will carry that dependency.  Which probably isn't a problem in this case, but just something to note.)